# TOR Peer-To-Peer Application in C

Tags: c, proxy, chat, p2p, tor

i am writing a peer-to-peer chat application in C and would like to extend it using TOR as transport medium. Since i have never used TOR before and i roughly know how it works; i have no idea how to achieve that.

By all means, both clients are listening for connection requests on a specific TCP port (defined by user). What do i have to do, so that e.g Client A connects to Client B (assuming both have TOR client installed)? Due to some research i found out that i have to connect to localhost:9050 where the TOR client is listening and then i think i have to craft a SOCKS4/5 pdu to connect to the proxy??

If that's right, could someone explain me this in detail? Furthermore are there any libs i can use for connecting to a socks proxy (for C, OS: GNU/Linux, BSD)?

Thanks in advance!